# cannot find map.png when it is in the same place

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

For a school project i have to create what they call is a my radar it so i chose to use a map that represents the world and it does not charge ans it segfault, it has sefgaulted when i tried to had tower so the future planes will go to there tower

```
include <SFML/Graphics.h>
#include "../include/struct.h"
#include "../include/my.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_TOWERS 10 //

sfSprite* create_background(sfRenderWindow* window, sfVideoMode mode)
{
    sfTexture* background_texture;
    sfSprite* background;
    sfVector2u textureSize;
    float scaleX;
    float scaleY;

    background_texture = sfTexture_createFromFile("map.png", NULL);
    background = sfSprite_create();
    sfSprite_setTexture(background, background_texture, sfTrue);
    textureSize = sfTexture_getSize(background_texture);
    scaleX = (float)mode.width / textureSize.x;
    scaleY = (float)mode.height / textureSize.y;
    sfSprite_setScale(background, (sfVector2f){scaleX, scaleY});
    return background;
}

void initializing_game(GameData* game, sfVideoMode mode) {
    game->window = sfRenderWindow_create(mode, "my_radar", sfResize | sfClose, NULL);
    if (!game->window) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create window\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // Exit if there is an error
    }

    game->background = create_background(game->window, mode);
    if (!game->background) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create background\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // Exit if there is an error
    }

    // Read tower positions from file
    FILE* file = fopen("towers_pos", "r");
    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open tower_positions.txt\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // Exit if there is an error
    }

    // Create towers
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TOWERS; i++) {
        float x, y;
        if (fscanf(file, "%f %f", &x, &y) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading tower position from file\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // Exit if there is an error
        }

        create_tower(&game->towers[i], x, y, game->window);
    }

    fclose(file);
}

void processing_events(GameData* game)
{
    sfEvent event;

    while (sfRenderWindow_pollEvent(game->window, &event)) {
        if (event.type == sfEvtClosed)
            sfRenderWindow_close(game->window);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    sfVideoMode mode = {800, 600, 32};
    GameData game;

    initializing_game(&game, mode);
    while (sfRenderWindow_isOpen(game.window)) {
        processing_events(&game);
        sfRenderWindow_clear(game.window, sfBlack);
        sfRenderWindow_drawSprite(game.window, game.background, NULL);
        draw_towers(&game);
        sfRenderWindow_display(game.window);
    }
    cleaning_game(&game);
    return 0;
}
```

he is my code i can had some images i have debugged it said that there is a problem with sfspirte get_size  here is the error message i have

```
Failed to load image "map.png". Reason: Unable to open file
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
0x00007ffff7f993b4 in sfTexture_getSize () from /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-graphics.so.2.5
```

i just want to have a map with the tower and there circle

Comment: i can had more informations if needed

Comment: Is map.png in the same directory you run the program from?

Comment: yes the map.png is in the same directory

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you can narrow down your issue to an error while opening that file, then you could remove unrelated code from your example. That makes it easier to focus on the problem.

Comment: Do not post images of text.  Instead, copy and paste the text itself into the question.  Format it as a code block if it is preformatted.

Comment: The only place where `map.png` is found in the code is `background_texture = sfTexture_createFromFile("map.png", NULL);`. You do not check the return value and handle any errors accordingly. Instead you happily pass that pointer to other functions which probably causes your segmentation fault. You should always check functions for any error indication.

Comment: In which folder is that png file located? In which folder are you when you call your program? What access privileges does that png file have? Does your user have read permission on it?

Comment: @Gerhardh so i have a folder called src with my programs plus the images so i just called it map.png because they are in the same folder the map used to charge but when i added the tower it started segfaulting

Comment: Sometimes software makes bad assumptions that lead to misattributing the cause of an error.  For example, assuming that a failure to open a file results from it not being present, when in fact it was because the user did not have permission to open it.  In this case, however, it is more likely that the file really isn't found, probably because the working directory for your runs is not what you think it is.

Comment: thanks you i think i have solved the segfault problem i still have one issues i will try to figure it out

Comment: In particular, note well that the location of your source file has little to do with the working directory for a run of your binary.  That the image is collocated with the source file does not imply that the program should be able to find it by the name alone.

Comment: You did not really answer my questions about which folders are involved or what permissions you have. If you have solved the issue, then you could write an answer telling what was wrong.